# Can I use the clock from a bag in ROS2?

Tags: ros, ros2, bagfile, clock

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't see an option for `ros2 bag play --clock <bag>`, is there an equivalent feature in ROS2 yet?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346845/can-i-use-the-clock-from-a-bag-in-ros2?/) by [dawonn_haval](https://answers.ros.org/users/52574/dawonn_haval/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2020-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosbag2` is not yet clock-aware. See the related GitHub ticket here: https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2/issues/99

You can always record and playback the `/clock` topic, but `rosbag2` doesn't support features like jumping to timepoints or changing the rate of playback.

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2020-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0